# SQL SUM columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon,

I currently have the query:

```
SELECT erp_user.login, 
SUM(invoice_header.invoice_amount) as 'Invoices Billed'
FROM erp_user
LEFT JOIN order_header ON erp_user.erp_user_id = order_header.req_by
LEFT JOIN invoice_instruct_header ON order_header.order_id = invoice_instruct_header.order_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_header ON invoice_instruct_header.instruct_id = invoice_header.instruct_no
WHERE erp_user.supervisor_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id_type = 'I' AND erp_user.company_id IS NOT NULL  AND erp_user.is_active = 1 
GROUP BY erp_user.login
```

It gives me a list of total billing in our system by employee where the employee is signed to a job on the job header.

I would love to add the total amount of open PO's to this query so I added:

```
SELECT erp_user.login, SUM(invoice_header.invoice_amount) as 'Invoices Billed', sum(po_header.po_amount) AS "Open PO's"
FROM erp_user
LEFT JOIN order_header ON erp_user.erp_user_id = order_header.req_by
LEFT JOIN invoice_instruct_header ON order_header.order_id = invoice_instruct_header.order_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_header ON invoice_instruct_header.instruct_id = invoice_header.instruct_no
LEFT JOIN po_header ON order_header.order_id = po_header.order_id
WHERE erp_user.supervisor_id IS NOT NULL AND user_id_type = 'I' AND erp_user.company_id IS NOT NULL  AND erp_user.is_active = 1  AND po_header.status = 1
GROUP BY erp_user.login
ORDER BY "Open PO's"
```

That query gives me numbers in my Open PO's column, but they are incorrect and I'm at the point now where I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I don't mind doing the work, just need a pointer. Thanks!

Comment: We'd need more info about your data. Based on your query, it seems that a invoice can only ever have one employee associated with it. Can a PO have more than one employee? What your tables look like would be a good start.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Regarding the invoice/query, the invoice is associated with an instruction number, the instruction number is associated with an order, and the order is associated with an employee. A PO is associated with an order number.

And I apologize for the incorrect tag. It's MS Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of conbination of Left join and Where clause.

```
SELECT erp_user.login
, SUM(invoice_header.invoice_amount) as 'Invoices Billed'
, sum(CASE WHEN po_header.status = 1 THEN po_header.po_amount ELSE 0 END) AS "Open PO's"
FROM erp_user
LEFT JOIN order_header ON erp_user.erp_user_id = order_header.req_by
LEFT JOIN invoice_instruct_header ON order_header.order_id = invoice_instruct_header.order_id
LEFT JOIN invoice_header ON invoice_instruct_header.instruct_id = invoice_header.instruct_no
LEFT JOIN po_header ON order_header.order_id = po_header.order_id
WHERE erp_user.supervisor_id IS NOT NULL 
AND user_id_type = 'I' 
AND erp_user.company_id IS NOT NULL  
AND erp_user.is_active = 1 
GROUP BY erp_user.login
ORDER BY "Open PO's";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `po_header` joins to `order_header`, then in your original query it would be repeating each `po_header` for each `invoice_header` as well (leading to the incorrect calculation).

You could use `outer apply()` like so:

```
select 
    erp_user.login
  , [Invoices Billed] = sum(invoice_header.invoice_amount) 
  , x.[Open POs]
from erp_user
  left join order_header
    on erp_user.erp_user_id = order_header.req_by
  left join invoice_instruct_header
    on order_header.order_id = invoice_instruct_header.order_id
  left join invoice_header
    on invoice_instruct_header.instruct_id = invoice_header.instruct_no
  outer apply (
    select 
        [Open POs] = sum(po_header.po_amount)
    from po_header p
      inner join order_header oh 
        on oh.order_id = p.order_id
    where oh.req_by = erp_user.erp_user_id
  ) x
where erp_user.supervisor_id is not null 
  and erp_user.company_id is not null  
  and erp_user.is_active = 1 
  and user_id_type = 'I' 
group by erp_user.login
```